# glm binary variable using family= gaussian instead of binomial is it wrong?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

no this question is not a duplicate what i did is that i have 50 variables one qulitative y taken values 0 for normal cells and 1 for abnormal cells
and 49 quantitative variables 
what i wanted to do is using logistic regression to express y ~the other 49 variables 
but when coding i just used this glm formula glm(y~., data=mydt) and i did not mentioned the family so what i used really is not logistic model but model with family=gaussian

then now what i want to know is wht is the difference between the two models and if this did affect the results that i have 
i hope that is now clear
thanks a lot in advance for any help

Comment: It's not clear from your question which type is the outcome/response/dependent variable and which types are the predictor/independent variables. More detail about your particular problem and what you are trying to accomplish can help get better answers to your questions here.

Comment: Understanding what the difference is between linear & logistic regression is what the other thread is all about. If you read that & understand it, you will know what you need to answer your own question.

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked thread. Please 
read it. If it isn't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.

Comment: hi gung thanks for taking the time to answer my question 
I mentioned that it is not a duplicate i red the thread that is not exactly what i want.
I need to now the difference between glm using especially family gaussian and logistic regression 
in fact i just mentioned that normally i should use logistic regression in my work but i used glm with family gaussian i want to know if this affect the results i have had 
thanks a lot for any help